# Send emojis in email body in mailto link

Tags: html, emoji, mailto

I'm trying to generate an email that has emojis in the body from a mailto link that is opened with javascript like the following.

```
window.open(`mailto:?subject=Hello&body=${encodeURIComponenet('Hello ')}`)
```

The actual body text is generated dynamically and could include a variety of emojis but I can't get any of them to display correctly on a PC. They show as a rectangle with a question mark. They will display on Mac, or if they are used in the subject line on PC, but not in the body.

[Picture of what I'm seeing in windows mail app with the same message in the subject and the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhbGG.png)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a mac vs. PC thing. What else is different?

Comment: It is exactly the same code on Mac and PC. I included of picture of what I'm seeing in windows mail app on PC

Comment: That's what I meant. The Windows Mail app is probably the culprit, not the operating system itself. This is an important detail. I found this, but not sure if this is helpful: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-live-mail-mailto-protocoll-link-utf8-chars/70c99781-7f72-4c17-b678-4074576bf1f4

Comment: The RFC has some examples you could try (you can add a quoted-printable encoding marker): https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068#section-6.3